# String constant pool memory

Tags: java, string, heap-memory

Suppose there are 2 web applications deployed on a same http server. Will both the applications have only one String constant pool memory or it will be per application?

Eg :

Application 1 :
String s="Hello";

Application 2 :
String t="Hello";

Will there be 2 objects created in there respective string constant pool memory or there will be only one object ?

Comment: Define "same server".  Do you mean on the same machine?  Both in a container like tomcat?  In the same JVM?

Comment: The Server may be tomcat server.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it really clear what you are asking about. And also do some prior research. I am pretty sure you aren't the first person asking such questions.

Answer (score 1):

The constant string pool is per JVM process. If you have two applications running in a JVM instance each (i.e. you can see two java processes in your process list) there will be two different pools.

If we're talking about e.g. two web applications running on the same HTTP server both will share the same pool.

So it depends on what you mean by "application" and "server" but I think this post should answer all variations.

There is a way to find out if both applications share the same pool by using `String#intern`:

```
public class StringPoolTest {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2_1 = "H";
        String s2_2 = "ello";
        String s2 = s2_1 + s2_2;

        System.out.println("s1 identity: " + System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println("s2 identity: " + System.identityHashCode(s2));

        s1 = s1.intern();
        s2 = s2.intern();

        System.out.println("s1 identity: " + System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println("s2 identity: " + System.identityHashCode(s2));
    }
}
```

After calling `intern` the second set of `System.out.println` shows the same ID:

> s1 identity: 366712642
>
> s2 identity: 1829164700
>
> s1 identity: 366712642
>
> s2 identity: 366712642

If you put some logging code into your two applications showing the hash after calling `intern` on the same text and you can see the same hash, you can be quite sure that they use the same pool.